# Understanding function callback & memory leak js

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, callback

I would like to understand if these functions does leak some memory or not?

**example 1**

```
function setUserData(data, cb){
 // do some magic here
  if(cb){
     cb();
    delete cb; 
    // OR 
    cb = null;
   }
 }

setUserData('test', reloadUserData);
```

**example 2**

```
let setUserData = function update(data, cb){
// do some magic here
  if(cb){
     cb();
     cb= null;
   }
  setUserData = null;
}

setUserData('test', reloadUserData);
```

Should I nullify the cb objects after calling the cb?

Comment: The `cb` variable in memory won't generate a memory leak problem.  Moreover, the assignment to null is not "cleaning" the current value of `cb` in memory.

Comment: `cb` is a local varable, it's destroyed when the function ends, since there's no closure here. What matters is the lifetime of the function in the caller.

Comment: In javascript funtions are first class objects they behave just like any other object passed in as a parameter, you can modify a member that's inside or add new members to it and it will reflect in the original object but it makes no sense to delete the main object itself